# Rails loading of non-ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails 3 app that defines a few non-ActiveRecord models. All of these are defined in `app/models/module_name`. I have the following in all_autoload_paths:

```
[4] pry(main)> app._all_autoload_paths
=> ["/Users/mandar/myapp/lib",
 "/Users/mandar/myapp/app/assets",
 "/Users/mandar/myapp/app/controllers",
 "/Users/mandar/myapp/app/helpers",
 "/Users/mandar/myapp/app/models"]
```

Is there a difference between how the following 2 class definitions are handled when loading models?

```rb
module A
    class X
        # some code
    end
end
```

and

```rb
class A::Y
    # some code
end
```

The reason I ask this is sometimes I've seen a `uninitialized constant A::Y - NameError` error.

**Update:** Following Sibevin's answer, I'd like to make this clearer. Currently, I have the following file structure:

```
app
  - models
    - a
      - x.rb
      - y.rb
```

I have seen the error for Y which uses the `ModuleName::ClassName` syntax, but almost never for X.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

They should be no difference, but I usually separate them into individual files.

You can create a folder `app/models/a/` first  and put your `class A::X` in `app/models/a/x.rb`.

Similarly, `app/models/a/y.rb` for `class A::Y`.

BTW, `app/models/a.rb` for your `module A` if needed.

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I never use the 2nd format to declare a class in a module. Maybe the following doc can answer your question:

[Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup)

> If you've ever tried to take a short-cut when re-opening a module, you
>   may have noticed that constants from skipped namespaces aren't
>   available. This is because the outer namespaces are not added to
>   Module.nesting.

Comment: That's the file structure I have currently. Sorry for not being precise. I'll update the question accordingly.